# Why does Android Studio close automatically in Windows 7

Tags: android-studio

I am using **android** **studio** **1.3.2**. When I start it works fine but after some time it will close automatically without any kind of message or error. What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you look into the windows event log?

Comment: Can you upgrade to a newer version? Without further details, we cannot say what might be wrong, but it has had a reputation for being buggy...

Answer (score 0):

try to update your android studio as 1.3.2 is very old version and it has some bugs as well . i hope thi will help you.